# How to break an ajax event life cycle in Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

After an ajax event happening, for example "tabChange", i need to check in backing bean a boolean value, if it is true, it should breaks the event life cycle and prevent updating the form, otherwise it should do whole event life cycle and updating the form.
How can break an event ?

Comment: Preventing the ajax to start is the only option. If you are in the listener or action, the values are already applied to the model. You can do this by using the onstart attribute, call a javascript function and return false from there. How you do the server side check is up to you. Maybe a remote command works or setting the some javascript variable in a previous response or...

Comment: I doubt these requirements are well thought out, but you can do something like that with a `PhaseListener` and a `javax.faces.context.FacesContext.responseComplete()` call.